# logic/design for storing achievments and progress for users

Tags: database-design, google-app-engine

I have a game with a databse of users, I now want to implement unlockable achievments in my game. How would I best go about saving this data for each user? I am still fairly new to using a database.

Relevant info:

- Each user in the users-table has an ID
- There are 30+ achievments
- Many achievments are longer processes, that require the ability to save the progress of that achievment for users, ex: Win 8 rounds in a row.
- When the game is started it should load all finished/unfinished achievments as well as progress for each.

I don't even know where to start, any sort of help is appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be a good idea to create an 'Achievement' table with required condition to be unlock (ex:Win 8 rounds in a row) and  an association table 'UserAchevement' to indicate users.the same To store every user progress (the number of Wining round for exemple) a 'Progress' table is needed.

Comment: Thanks, so in "UserAchievment" table I would just store userID and if the achievment is unlocked or not (one column for each achievment)? Then in the progress table I would store the userID and the progress of each achievment for a user (one column for each achievment)?

Comment: Is there any way you could add an example for the colums/rows in your answer? would help me understand what you mean

Comment: 'UserAchievment' store only user whom unlock an achievment. if in the progress table a user for exemple win 8 rounds then a row would be insert into 'UserAchievment' (USER_ID,Achievment_ID, and other attribute). and obvously in every win u will or the app will verfy the 'progress' table to identify if user has win 8 rounds to insert the achevement into 'UserAchievment' table.

Comment: Thanks, so that means that if I have 30 achievments, each user will create 30 rows both in 'progress' and 'UserAchievment', is that okay? That can create two pretty big tables if I get many users.

Comment: not exactly, a user will create 1 row in  "UserAchievment" if the user progress is complete for example : in the 'progress' table user x has win 7 round until now there is no  achievment and thus no row is inserted into "UserAchievment" but when for exemple in progress table we have 'Round = 8' here a row will be insert into '"UserAchievment" '  and yes two pretty big tables  indeed

Comment: Thanks for your help, I didnt know it was okay to create tables that big